# Как запустить крон в laravel 2 раза в день?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Запустил сервер. Написал скрипт, который нужно выполнять два раза в день(утром и вечером). Вот команда, которую `cron` должен запускать `php artisan command:cron`. Как запускать эту команду два раза в день?

```
* * * * * php /var/www/blog schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `crontab -e` далее в формате крона вводите инструкцию.

Comment: ну хотя бы описание [использованной метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) посмотрели бы, что ли.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Такой вопрос. Я щас обновил вопрос. Добавил скрин того, что добавил в крон. Крон будет использовать заданное расписание, которое находится в файле `Kernel.php`?

Comment: Как запускать эту команду два раза в день: `0 0,12 * * * php /var/www/blog schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1` например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-под пользователя, из под которого должен выполняться скрипт, выполнить команду:

```
crontab -e
```

Откроется редактор по умолчанию (vim/nano)

Ввести необходимую строку cron в этом редакторе:

0 7,19 * * * php /var/www/blog schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1

Выйти из редактора, сохранив изменения.
Появится сообщение о том, что crontab обновлён.
Задача будет выполняться каждый день в 7:00 и в 19:00(время можно скорректировать в строке крон).